# How to convert long to string without sprintf()?

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, printf

I need to convert longs to string, but I can't use `sprintf()`.

Here's my code

```
char *ultostr(unsigned long value, char *ptr, int base)
{
    unsigned long t = 0; 
    unsigned long res = 0;
    unsigned long tmp;
    int count = 0;

    tmp = value;

    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (tmp == 0)
    {
        count++;
    }

    while(tmp > 0)
    {
        tmp = tmp/base;
        count++;
    }

    ptr += count;
    *ptr = '\0';

    do
    {
        t = value / base;
        res = value - (base*t);

        if (res < 10)
        {
            * -- ptr = '0' + res;
        }
        else if ((res >= 10) && (res < 16))
        {
            * --ptr = 'A' - 10 + res;
        }

        value = t;
    } while (value != 0);

   return(ptr);
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with your solution?

Comment: I can certainly write something smaller than that (because I've written this sort of code many times - practice, practice and more practice, and you may achieve something less imperfect [calling what I do "perfect" is probably not right]), but I don't see a question, so not sure what you want to have answered?

Comment: The code you've got is not bad. What is your question?

Comment: It depends why you can't use `sprintf`. If it's because you're on a non-standard C++ implementation where it's missing, then the answer might be different from if it's because you're implementing (one small part of) `sprintf` as an exercise.

Comment: @SteveJessop 90% it's the latter :)

Comment: @icepack: right, but until the questioner says so, all he's going to get is variants on the existing answers, "use `stringstream`"!

Answer (score 2):

You could use stringstream I think.

```
#include <sstream>
...
std::stringstream x;
x << 1123;
cout << x.str().c_str();
```

(x.str().c_str() makes it char*)
it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringstream`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ostringstream ss;
    long i = 10;
    ss << i;
    string str = ss.str();
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of stream objects like [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    long int i = 10000;

    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string str;

    ss << i;

    str = ss.str();

    std::cout << str; // 10000
}
```

[***Live Demo***](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%243141)

Comment: You don't really need the `str` variable, you can `std::cout << ss.str();`

Comment: `to_string` uses `sprintf` internally. If the OP's requirement is deep, then `to_string` would be equally prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
 #include<sstream>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    unsigned long d = 1234567;
    std::stringstream m_ss;
    m_ss << d;
    std::string my_str;
    m_ss >> my_str;
    std::cout<<my_str<<std::endl;

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: OMG, yesterdays' 3 answers with `stringstream` probably not enough